# Calculate the MU-numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence

The first two MU-numbers are 2 and 3.  Every other MU-number is the smallest number not yet appeared that can be expressed as the product of two earlier distinct MU-numbers in exactly one way.

Here are the first 10

```
2, 3, 6, 12, 18, 24, 48, 54, 96, 162
```

### Task

Given a positive number calculate and output the **n**th MU-number.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) competition so you should aim to make your source code as small as possible.

[OEIS A007335](http://oeis.org/A007335)

Comment: 0-indexing or 1-indexing?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Either is fine.

Comment: Any idea why these are called MU-numbers? (Wild guess: Multiplication Unique?)

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
@u+Gfq2l@GcLTGheGQhB2
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40u%2BGfq2l%40GcLTGheGQhB2&input=9&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40u%2BGfq2l%40GcLTGheGQhB2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&debug=0)

0-indexed.

#### Explanation

```
@u+Gfq2l@GcLTGheGQhB2Q    Implicitly append Q and read+eval input to it.
                  hB2     Take the list [2, 2 + 1].
 u               Q        Put the list in G and apply this Q times:
               eG           Get last number in G.
              h             Add one.
    f                       Starting from that, find the first T such that:
          cLTG                Divide T by each of the numbers in G.
        @G                    Find the quotients that are also in G.
       l                      Get the number of such quotients.
     q2                       Check that it equals 2.
  +G                        Append that T to G.
@                    Q    Get the Q'th number in G.
```

Comment: The `@` sign on the last line is misaligned. I can't make a suggested edit, since it's a 2-character change.

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>80</s> 77 bytes

```
l#(a:b)|[x]<-[a|i<-l,j<-l,i<j,i*j==a]=a:(a:l)#b|1<2=l#b
((2:3:[2,3]#[4..])!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDsIgEADQ3a@4hg5gaBPBiXBfQhiOpI2HZ9O0Dg78O@rypveg87mI9C5KUyimpU@OU6LGcRJb/3Cslq8VkTJS@C0xqrRbdCiqXFbU2gUfkrM@q3Sf52yGwfQX8QYI@8HbG0ZYwfcv)

How it works

```
2:3:             -- start the list with 2 and 3 and append a call to # with
    [2,3]        -- the list so far and
         #[4..]  -- list of candidate elements

l # (a:b)        -- l -> list so far, a -> next candidate element, b -> rest c.el.
  | [x]<-[...]   -- if the list [...] is a singleton list
    =a:(a:l#b) -- the result is a followed by a recursive call with l extended
                    by a and b
  | 1<2=l#b      -- if it's not a singleton list, drop a and retry with b

                 -- the [...] list is
 [ i<-l,j<-l,    -- loop i through l and j through l and whenever   
       i<j,      -- i<j and
       i*j==a]   -- i*j==a
  a|             -- add a to the list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>127</s> <s>118</s> <s>111</s> <s>108</s> <s>105</s> <s>100</s> <s>98</s> 90 bytes

8 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
r=3:2;for(i in 1:scan())r=c(min((g=(r%o%r)[i:-1<i])[colSums(g%o%g==g*g)+g%in%r<3]),r);r[3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg5DsIwEAXQ/p8ijaUZFgnHrElccgGWKkqBIjAjJQ6agCgQZze88ml636W70ulw3nP2UIlP@iT1rsjL26AkmcTMFmN7icSsvqVeIlHwpGYwyrUUc1tJw3U7dMdXP1L4f/A@TAJPg5FotHINz5RLrV2TvgwL5IADlsAKWAMbYAvsALtIPw)

Comment: It took me forever to realize that `<` has lower precedence than `+` so I couldn't figure out what in the heck `+g%in%r<3` was doing, and while I was doing that, you golfed down the two parts I was going to suggest... +1

Comment: @Giuseppe I just started to learn R today... nice to meet a decent R golfer.

Comment: I was going to say the same to you.............

Comment: Ah, one more thing, you can use [`n=scan()`](https://tio.run/##Dcq9CoQwDADgV3EpJP4Mnri05ikcS4ejcCGgKUScDp@99ps/q1Xpyl8FDEYfv4RfMZBOtJu94p8JzBVnGMVP8yaprQw2nqLAMZdjv88LuBUm4p5xYCfqbFsS4hMsaqprfQE "R – Try It Online") instead of a function definition to read from stdin; that'll get you under 100

Comment: Fails for input: `0`

Comment: @Rift I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒcP€ḟ⁸ṢŒgLÞḢḢṭ
2,3Ç¡ị@
```

A monadic link, 1-indexed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opOSAR01rHu6Y/6hxx8Odi45OSvc5PO/hjkUgtHMtl5GO8eH2Qwsf7u52@P//vzkA)**

#### How?

```
ŒcP€ḟ⁸ṢŒgLÞḢḢṭ - Link 1, add the next number: list, a  e.g. [2,3,6,12,18,24]
Œc             - unordered pairs                            [[2,3],[2,6],[2,12],[2,18],[2,24],[3,6],[3,12],[3,18],[3,24],[6,12],[6,18],[6,24],[12,18],[12,24],[18,24]]
  P€           - product of €ach                            [6,12,24,36,48,18,36,54,72,72,108,144,216,288,432]
     ⁸         - chain's left argument, a                   [2,3,6,12,18,24]
    ḟ          - filter discard                             [36,48,36,54,72,72,108,144,216,288,432]
      Ṣ        - sort                                       [36,36,48,54,72,72,108,144,216,288,432]
       Œg      - group runs of equal elements               [[36,36],[48],[54],[72,72],[108],[144],[216],[288],[432]]
          Þ    - sort by:
         L     -   length                                   [[48],[54],[108],[144],[216],[288],[432],[36,36],[72,72]]
           Ḣ   - head                                       [48]
            Ḣ  - head                                       48
             ṭ - tack to a                                  [2,3,6,12,18,24,48]

2,3Ç¡ị@ - Link: number, i                              e.g. 7
2,3     - literal [2,3]                                     [2,3]
    ¡   - repeat i times:
   Ç    -   call last link (1) as a monad                   [2,3,6,12,18,24,48,54,96]
     ị@ - index into with swapped @rguments (with i)        48
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam (32 bytes)

```
4,{_2m*{~>},::*1$-$e`$0=|}qi*-2=
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=4%2C%7B_2m*%7B~%3E%7D%2C%3A%3A*1%24-%24e%60%240%3D%7C%7Dqi*-2%3D&input=9) with 0-indexing.

I'm not sure there's much to be done beyond a trivial translation of the spec with one exception: by starting with a list of `[0 1 2 3]` (instead of `[2, 3]`) I save one byte immediately on initialisation and another two by being able to do `0=|` (adding just the new element because its frequency is `1` and is already in the list), but don't introduce any false elements because for every `x` in the list `0*x` and `1*x` are already in the list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>127</s> 118 bytes

```python
n=input()
l=[2,3]
exec't=sorted(x*y for i,x in enumerate(l)for y in l[i+1:]);l+=min(t,key=(l+t).count),;'*n
print l[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEADAu6/wFo0SmvTW4EuCh5Bu6VKzil1BX2@b6zCp8TvS0js5pFRYaRHctti7F1DhGNh9Y2Z4qjo2@YpZoq0SSQKVE/LOoIK@uF0YNjTzw@s1GHciKbYfaE4Fw3o6YiHWdh1GEikj8X@T732@/QA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 154 bytes

simple modification of the code found at oeis link

```
(s={2,3};Do[n=Select[Split@Sort@Flatten@Table[s[[j]]s[[k]],{j,Length@s},{k,j+1,Length@s}],#[[1]]>s[[-1]]&&Length@#==1&][[1,1]];AppendTo[s,n],{#}];s[[#]])&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 130 bytes

0-indexed

```php
for($r=[2,3];!$r[$argn];$r[]=$l=min($m)/2){$m=[];foreach($r as$x)foreach($r as$y)($p=$x*$y)<=$l|$y==$x?:$m[$p]+=$p;}echo$r[$argn];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49D4JAEER7foXiFpyaaNDKY0NhKGy0sbtcCCEnRyKwWSkgfvz187QxdvMyeZkhSy5JyVJgmDvO2VDHfd1W0SvLj6fzYZ8JGUDBVYvhdh1Kd@k4AkYVLzdaToHVt9TSJ41wxaZuI2jEKhZ3aFBp6QVTlNZLk@IGg/jnUURACMPcp8T7DxjRY7qDRgHpBQLJpylt91tyM@K67fPPDyHdGw)

Expanded

```php
for($r=[2,3];!$r[$argn]; #set the first to items and loop till search item exists
$r[]=$l=min($m)/2){ # add the half of the minimum of found values to the result array
  $m=[]; # start with empty array
  foreach($r as$x) # loop through result array
    foreach($r as$y) # loop through result array
      ($p=$x*$y)<=$l|$y==$x? # if product is greater as last value and we do multiple two distinct values
        :$m[$p]+=$p; # add 2 times or more the product to array so we drop 36 cause it will be 144  
}
echo$r[$argn]; # Output
```

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 159 bytes

0-indexed

```php
for($r=[2,3];!$r[$argn];$r[]=$l=min(array_diff_key($m,$d))){$d=$m=[];foreach($r as$x)foreach($r as$y)$x<$y?${dm[$m[$p=$x*$y]<1&$p>$l]}[$p]=$p:0;}echo$r[$argn];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU47C8IwGNz9FT4OacTBx2YaHcTBRRe3EkJoU1u07cenQ4PoX6/RRYQb7gF3RwV18YYK6jnmhg07avhe1ufotTOH42m/3QnZg@VzrYbz2VB2ecMRWCWL6VLLATj5hloGphWuqirryDJbb7Iyz83F@QjVFJkQ4oFMoVKJlqHE2bQIRX17Qyv@tRdoY/gNHlmVIIAU2gm8judj0BpX/QxeWKPVTD5dWjS/G92IuKzv5nNSyO4N)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 161 bytes

0-indexed

```php
for($r=[2,3];!$r[$argn];$r[]=$l=min(array_diff($m,$d))){$d=$m=[];foreach($r as$x)foreach($r as$y)$x<$y?${dm[!in_array($p=$x*$y,$m)&$p>$l]}[]=$p:0;}echo$r[$argn];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49C8IwGIR3f4UfhyTSwY/NGB3EwUUXtxJCsK0NmPTl1aFF9K/X6iJudxw891BJ7WpDJfVy5oot51Tx3ceLeO3s4Xjab3dS9eD4EvVwNh2qtqhYgHU6TxZGDcDpdzSqS0bjqoOPwjG7xma@KARCgkxK@UCmEXRqVAfI3bnsIH13Qy3/eyNRr9Bs8MhCOvDRflkCpFFP0CQIcgxa42qenz9aTtUzP5fVT6QdEft4tx9Nqdo3)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 140 bytes

```
(t=1;s={2,3};While[t<#,s=AppendTo[s,Sort[Select[First/@Select[Tally[Times@@@Permutations[s,{2}]],#[[2]]==2&],#>Last@s&]][[1]]];t++];s[[#]])&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 25 bytes

```
3:i:"t&*9B#u2=)yX-X<h]2_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/YKtNKqURNy9JJudTIVrMyQjfCJiPWKF7zv0vIf0MuIy5jLkMDAA)

#### Explanation

```
3:     % Push [1 2 3]. Initial array of MU numbers, to be extended with more numbers
i:     % Input n. Push [1 2 ... n]
"      % Do this n times
  t    %   Duplicate array of MU numbers so far
  &*   %   Matrix of pair-wise products
  9B   %   Push 9 in binary, that is, [1 0 0 1]
  #    %   Specify that next function will produce its first and fourth ouputs
  u    %   Unique: pushes unique entries (first output) and their counts (fourth)
  2=   %   True for counts that equal 2
  )    %   Keep only unique entries with count 2
  y    %   Duplicate (from below) array of MU numbers so far
  X-   %   Set difference
  X<   %   Minimum. This is the new MU number
  h    %   Concatenate vertically horizontally to extend the array
]      % End
2_     % Push 2 negated, that is, -2
)      % Get entry at position -2, that is, third-last. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>119</s> <s>118</s> 117 bytes

A recursive function that takes a 0-based index.

```js
f=(n,a=[2,m=3])=>a[n]||a.map(c=>a.map(d=>c<d&(d*=c)>m?b[d]=b[d]/0||d:0),b=[])|f(n,a.push(m=b.sort((a,b)=>a-b)[0])&&a)
```

#### How?

At each iteration of ***f()***, we use the last term ***m*** of the sequence and an initially empty array ***b*** to identify the next term. For each product ***d > m*** of two earlier distinct MU-numbers, we do:

```js
b[d] = b[d] / 0 || d
```

and then keep the minimum value of ***b***.

The above expression is evaluated as follows:

```
b[d]               | b[d] / 0  | b[d] / 0 || d
-------------------+-----------+--------------
undefined          | NaN       | d
already equal to d | +Infinity | +Infinity
+Infinity          | +Infinity | +Infinity
```

This guarantees that products which can be expressed in more than one way will never be selected.

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = (n, a = [2, m = 3]) =>           // given: n = input, a[] = MU array, m = last term
  a[n] ||                            // if a[n] is defined, return it
  a.map(c =>                         // else for each value c in a[]:
    a.map(d =>                       //   and for each value d in a[]:
      c < d &                        //     if c is less than d and
      (d *= c) > m ?                 //     d = d * c is greater than m:
        b[d] = b[d] / 0 || d         //       b[d] = either d or +Infinity (see 'How?')
      :                              //     else:
        0                            //       do nothing
    ),                               //   end of inner map()
    b = []                           //   initialization of b[]
  ) |                                // end of outer map()
  f(                                 // do a recursive call:
    n,                               //   - with n
    a.push(                          //   - push in a[]:
      m = b.sort((a, b) => a - b)[0] //     m = minimum value of b[]
    ) && a                           //     and use a[] as the 2nd parameter
  )                                  // end of recursive call
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,a=[2,m=3])=>a[n]||a.map(c=>a.map(d=>c<d&(d*=c)>m?b[d]=b[d]/0||d:0),b=[])|f(n,a.push(m=b.sort((a,b)=>a-b)[0])&&a)

for(var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  console.log('MU[' + n + '] = ' + f(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 96 bytes

```
{(2,3,{first *∉@_,@_.combinations(2).classify({[*]
$_}).grep(*.value==1)».key.sort}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc1RCsIgGADgq/wPI1Tkhy3qZQx2j7HEhgtpm6IuEPG9ztRbR@ki1neBzyq3nMsa4TBDVxJp@JGnWTsfgH2fr17wXuBk1qveZNBm86ShOC3Sez1HkgY2QiUyxZtTljB8yGVXXVfTzxvvKqI3LmREZHSoxJhLC15GWKX9fxwu9aktPw)

- `2, 3, { ... } ... *` is an infinite sequence where each element starting with the third is computed by the brace-delimited code block.  Since the code block takes its arguments via the slurpy `@_` array, it receives the entire current sequence in that array.
- `@_.combinations(2)` is a sequence of all 2-element combinations of `@_`.
- `.classify({ [*] $_ })` classifies each 2-tuple by its product, producing a hash where the products are the keys and the values are the list of 2-tuples that have that product.
- `.grep(*.value == 1)` selects those key-value pairs from the hash where the value (ie, the list of pairs having that key as a product) has a size of 1.
- `».key` selects only the keys of each pair.  This is the list of products that arise from only one combination of factors of the current sequence.
- `.sort` sorts the products numerically.
- `first * ∉ @_, ...` finds the first of those products that has not already appeared in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python <s>3</s> 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>167</s> <s>139</s> <s>136</s> <s>133</s> <s>123</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> 118 bytes

```python
a=[2,3];exec'p=[x*y for x in a for y in a if x-y];a+=min(q for q in p if p.count(q)+(q in a)<3),;'*input();print a[-2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jck9DsMgDEDhq3gL5KcDUSfKSRCDFSWqhxoTEQlOTxS6Pb1Pav5GNq2h82Zeg93Lvg3ifBkrHPGEAsSAPes/6YCy1GBxcj9ilbqlx@QxeW3x4qySnlS/qD@rnu0wEsuVlbZyEmdAv5jQ2vsG)

---

Thanks to @Mr.Xcoder and @LeakyNun for improvements!

Comment: [159 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxLEoIwEAXXcopZJhgsPjsVL0KxiJjoVMFMGMLC02Pi7lV1vw7f@GHqjsMLL4DRSWSeN8AlsMSyeDkPXpGx/dCabtTX0A9zKeBZYDYCSDDx8kSyEZk2ZU2r0UNWiGPGdryJi7ukNVTNmCDdWzdvLnerxtjzsCCp9Z9c8yNAksJl4p2iWvWj1qM@MsVMxdLbqabW1@IUBJOCJqVQ6@MH), just by removing unnecessary spaces and brackets.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks for the improvements. I'm not sure changing `p.count(q)==1` to `p.count(q)>0` is valid, because that's the code that ensures the "in exactly one way" condition of the challenge.

Comment: `p.count(q)-~(q in a)<=3` is equivalent to `p.count(q)+(q in a)<3`

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>117</s> <s>115</s> 113 bytes

```hs
n x=[a*b|[a,b]<-mapM id[1:x,x]]
d x=minimum[a|a<-n x,2==sum[1|b<-n x,b==a]]:x
l x|x<3=x+1:[2]|1>0=d$l$x-1
(!!0).l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcs9CgMhEEDh3lO4YJEfDeumEyc3yAnEYsQskags2QSm8O5GSPnxeE/cX4@ce6@cwOEpNIcyeKsKbneeotOGJHnP4ugl1VS@xWFDq8YgF4B9WLfwdwBA7w2xzKmRvQKdtXGLb/o2QxRZkNJshcM0zcdL7gVThe2d6kesXPcf)

Comment: The first line can be written as a useful idiom for operator cartesian product: `n x=(*)<$>x<*>1:x`